# Custom Attributes on an OAuth Authorization Code?

Tags: apigee

The documentation for the "Generate Authorization Code" policy (http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/api/oauth-flow-variables) indicates that custom attributes can be set on authorization codes via the  declarations.

How does one access these attributes? My goal is to associate a user ID with an authorization code, so that when it is exchanged for an access token, the user ID can be set as a custom attribute of the access token. I have the GenerateAuthorizationCode policy configured as follows:

```
<!-- language xml -->
<OAuthV2 enabled="true" continueOnError="false" async="false" name="GenerateAuthorizationCode">
    <Operation>GenerateAuthorizationCode</Operation>
    <ExpiresIn>120000</ExpiresIn>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute name="user_id" ref="request.queryparam.user_id" display="false"/>
    </Attributes>
    <GenerateResponse/>
</OAuthV2>
```

The intention is that my login app can generate a code by invoking a URL like: /authorization_code?response_type=code&client_id=foo&user_id=bar. This seems to work insofar as it generates a code and returns a redirect to the expected URL.

However, I have no idea how to access this attribute when I create a token. I tried configuring a GetOAuthV2Info policy on the token end point like this:

```
<!-- language xml -->
<GetOAuthV2Info async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="GetAuthorizationCodeAttributes">
    <AuthorizationCode>request.formparam.code</AuthorizationCode>
</GetOAuthV2Info>
```

in the hope that it would bring my code attributes into scope. But this causes a cryptic 500 response from Apigee: {"fault":{"faultstring":"NullPointerException","detail":{"errorcode":"Internal Server Error"}}}

Is this the right way to go about doing this? My ultimate objective is to associate a user ID with an authorization code, and with any access tokens derived from that authorization code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the authorization code is used to generate an access token and refresh token, the attributes from the authorization code are transferred to the new tokens.  When an access token is validated using the VerifyAccessToken operation of the OAuthV2 policy, the attributes are made available as flow variables, and any new access tokens that are generated from the refresh token also have these same attributes.

The GetOAuthV2Info policy can also be used to retrieve attributes associated with an access token.

See http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/api/oauth-flow-variables for the details of the flow variables generated in each of these cases.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize this happened automatically.